# Where can I dance "Mazurca" in Cape-Verde?

Tags: cape-verde, folk, dance

There is a variant of Mazurka in Cape-Verde. Are there some places or events where someone can see it and maybe give it a try?
I'm looking specially for Mazurca but any advice for dancing other traditional styles (rabolo, funana, coladeira) is also welcome.

Comment: are you asking if there are workshops in Cape Verde where they teach the mazurka? or somewhere else? If you check on Tripadvisor or Meetup, there are a lot of sports camps and workshops that you can learn the mazurka or Kizomba, etc.

Comment: @wilkvolk I prefer social dancing, just for fun. But actually anything will do, workshop is also good.

Comment: The Mazurka is a traditional dance in Cape Verde. There may be places or events where it can be seen and tried, as well as other traditional styles like Rabolo, Funana, and Coladeira. Any advice on where to find these dance opportunities would be appreciated.